# Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured

Tags: tomcat, classnotfoundexception

While trying to setup the tomcat server for my project I get the following error: Please see the full stack trace below:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.deploy.TcContainerDeployer
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:205)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:153)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1356)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:510)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:548)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)

Jun 5, 2013 12:23:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.deploy.TcContainerDeployer
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2832)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1359)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:510)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:548)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.deploy.TcContainerDeployer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:205)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1356)
    ... 20 more
Jun 5, 2013 12:23:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.deploy.TcContainerDeployer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:205)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1356)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:510)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:568)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Jun 5, 2013 12:23:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.deploy.TcContainerDeployer
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2832)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1359)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:510)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:568)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.deploy.TcContainerDeployer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:205)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1356)
    ... 20 more
Jun 5, 2013 12:23:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

What could be the possible error? In my server configuration I am using "Use Tomcat installation". I had to replace the server.xml, context.xml, portal-ext.properties, catalina.xml to match my project specifications; to use the jdbc resources etc. It is after this change that I find this error...

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444107/classnotfoundexception-when-starting-tomcat

Comment: portal-ext.properties are you liferay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is class not found. Find the library that has this class.

Ensure that you put all required libraries (*.jar) in WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the configuration files must have got corrupted. I faced this issue and fixed it by uninstaling and reinstalling tomcat. I use tomcat 7. But you can use the same commands with any version

```
sudo apt-get purge tomcat7
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

Now when you run the server it will show write or read failed in several files. Just give write and read permissions to those directories

```
chmod -R a+r {directory_name}
chmod -R a+w {directory_name}
```

Now go to tomcat folder and make a link of some files here

```
cd /usr/share/tomcat7
sudo ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/conf conf
sudo ln -s /var/log/tomcat7 log
sudo ln -s /etc/tomcat7/policy.d/03catalina.policy conf/catalina.policy
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /usr/share/tomcat7/conf
```

This will solve all the problems

Comment: The user doesn't make any mention of using a \*NIX system. This answer assumes otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My configuration is RHEL 7.6, Tomcat 8.5.40. I was installing and updating Tomcat using a script. I needed to update some files under the tomcat/conf directory after the initial installation. When I tried to restart tomcat, I was continually getting the following in catalina.out; and the problem was not recoverable:

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 229376K, used 15728K [0x000000078d000000, 0x000000079d000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 196608K, 8% used [0x000000078d000000,0x000000078df5c328,0x0000000799000000)
  from space 32768K, 0% used [0x000000079b000000,0x000000079b000000,0x000000079d000000)
  to   space 32768K, 0% used [0x0000000799000000,0x0000000799000000,0x000000079b000000)
 ParOldGen       total 524288K, used 0K [0x0000000727000000, 0x0000000747000000, 0x000000078d000000)
  object space 524288K, 0% used [0x0000000727000000,0x0000000727000000,0x0000000747000000)
 Metaspace       used 4924K, capacity 5216K, committed 5504K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 540K, capacity 600K, committed 640K, reserved 1048576K
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/var/lib/tomcat/conf/server.xml]
```

It turns out that the cause of the problem was trying to set the ownership and mode. I was doing:

```
sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat /var/lib/tomcat/conf
sudo chmod -R 600 /var/lib/tomcat/conf
sudo chmod -R 750 /var/lib/tomcat/conf/Catalina
```

If I set the permissions not in this blanket recursive manner. Everything remains fine, even though the end result (ownership and mode) of doing the recursive way or the manual way were exactly the same. It's an odd one; I hope this help someone. It took me two and a half days to track down this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally deleted `</host>` (closing tag line) in server.xml. After adding again the closing tag, the issue got resolved.