# ClassNotFound exception on deploy Eclipse (Luna) jersey and tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have error on deploy my Jersey web services in Tomcat. I have create a dynamic project 3.0 and after i convert this in Maven project.

I have installed this:

[Maven (Java EE) Integration for Eclipse WTP (Luna) 1.1.0](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-java-ee-integration-eclipse-wtp-luna#.VHXmC0Qc3FY)

and

[Maven Integration for Eclipse (Luna) 1.5.0](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-integration-eclipse-luna#.VHXmIkQc3FY)

But if i try  right-click on the project and do a Maven > Update project, this not  internally change the project configuration so the Maven dependencies are not copied to the /WEB-INF/lib folder.

So when i try to run in server i have this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
```

If i go to the Deployment Assembly i have:

Source: Maven Dependencies|Deploy path: WEB-INF/lib...i thinks this incorrect, is it?

Comment: Look this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022114/org-glassfish-jersey-servlet-servletcontainer-classnotfoundexception