# Tomcat 7 not started in jax-ws

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Jun 10, 2015 3:39:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal

SEVERE: A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component

[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/NewOpac]]

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at 

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at 

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 

[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/NewOpac]]

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)

    ... 7 more

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 

org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/JerseyServletContainerInitializer : 

Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class 

org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer)
    at 

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2899)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at 

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1652)
    at 

org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1562)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1270)
    at 

org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more


Jun 10, 2015 3:39:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 

Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at 

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at 

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component

 [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at 

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more


Jun 10, 2015 3:39:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]


    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more


Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 

[StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed 

during start

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)

    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

**Am getting this error how to solve this pls help me..**

Comment: This is just a stacktrace. What is your actual problem, and what have you tried to solve it?

Comment: tomcat 7 not started in java 6, i need to run my war in java 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below part of error suggests that you are using unsupported version of Jersey. Please check and use an appropriate version.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 

org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/JerseyServletContainerInitializer : 

Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class
```

Version 51.0 corresponds to Java 7. Are you starting tomcat with a version below Java 7?

Comment: Which version of Jersey are you using? You would need to either switch to Java7, rebuild code and deploy or use a compatible version of Jersey for Java 6. The issue is that, the version of Jersey you are currently using is compiled with Java 7 and your tomcat container is running with Java 6 and hence tomcat wont be able to read the classes which are compiled in Java 7. (Java has only backward compatibility).

Comment: my jersey version is 2.11, in this version would be supported in java 6 ?, which version would be supported in java 6, and how am get thus version , you have any links?, thanks..

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your configuration for Jersey 1.x is wrong. You can refer to the below post from SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022114/org-glassfish-jersey-servlet-servletcontainer-classnotfoundexception