# Multipart form data exception dropwizard

Tags: java, maven, jersey, dropwizard

I want to upload a file to a server from an html client.

---

***Exception***:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestExecutorFactory
```

---

***pom.xml***:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-forms</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160212</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

and this is run in the app class:

```
    env.jersey().register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    env.jersey().register(MultiPartConfigProvider.class);
    Execute execute=new Execute();
    env.jersey().register(execute);
```

I think the problem is by `pom.xml`but after a lot of change in pom don't get any result before
 this exception I have another exception that MultipartConfig class not exist so I register `MultipartFeature.class` and `multipartConfigProvider.class` but get this exception.
In the last exception (`MultipartConfig`) program exit after exception but in this exception 
 program not exit.
[project repository on github](https://github.com/MostafaEbrahimi/OnlineCoffeeMIPS-OCM-.git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer ClassNotFoundException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022114/org-glassfish-jersey-servlet-servletcontainer-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: Do you have the jersey-common jar in your dependency, if not please add it. For maven dependency refer https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/2.9

Comment: not effective :( .same exception @ClementAmarnath

Comment: is it correct to use `jersey version` 2.21 with `dropwizard` version 0.8.0?? @ClementAmarnath

Comment: How can it be duplicate? @VikrantKashyap

Comment: may you view my code on github? @ClementAmarnath

Comment: @mme - dropwizard 0.8.0(https://www.versioneye.com/java/io.dropwizard:dropwizard-jersey/0.8.0) recommendation for jersey is jersey 2.16, but as you are using 2.2.1 it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was solved by change to `dropwizard` version to 0.9.1
 and add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of :

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @mme - Great. If it resolved the problem, Please mark this as answered