# The pre provided answers did not help me in my case when I try to run my server in eclipse and it gives me a class not found exception

Tags: java, xml, servlets, glassfish

**This is my web.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">
<display-name>Book Service</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>book_service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
<param-value>bookservice</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>book_service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**This is my class file:**

```
package bookservice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Books {
    private static ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        books.add(new Book(1, "The Outliers", 500));
        books.add(new Book(2, "World Is Flat", 550));
    }
    public static List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }
}
```

**I used these jar files included in the image:** [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBStw.png)

**When I run my server I'm getting a 404 - Not Found error. Also there is an class not found exception in the console.**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1292)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1032)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4788)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5100)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

I copied all jar files to WEB-INF/lib.
I switched location in server properties and double clicked on server and change server locations to "Use tomcat installation".
I changed the web.xml according to the following link's solution

[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022114/org-glassfish-jersey-servlet-servletcontainer-classnotfoundexception)
**But any of these solutions didn't help me. How to handle this issue**

Comment: Hint: just "trying" solutions is probably not going to work.  You need to 1) **understand** the cause(s) of problem, then 2) **diagnose** your particular instance of the problem to figure out which of the possible causes applies to you.  Then **and only then** should you try to apply a relevant solution.

Comment: Hint 2:  Telling us *"I tried all of the solutions and they don't work"* won't help us.  It doesn't tell us which solutions you tried, whether they were applicable, whether you applied them **properly** and ... whether they made any difference.  It also doesn't help us find out what the real problem is.

Comment: Hint 3: The evidence suggests that your actual problem is precisely this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22023981/139985.  Read it carefully, and compare it with what you are doing.