# Api route configuration issue

Tags: java, eclipse, api, servlets

Can someone help me with this, i dunno know why but my guess is all about route configuration, so when i'm trying send a get request using postman, the response is 404 not found

my url request is:

```
http://localhost:8080/javaAPI/rest/secured/mesage
```

this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>javaAPI</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAVA API</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>test</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAVA API</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

And this is my class

```
package test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/secured")
public class SecuredResource {

    @GET
    @Path("message")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String securedMethod() {
        return "This API is secured";
    }
}
```

Comment: http://localhost:8080/javaAPI/rest/secured/`mesage` # http://localhost:8080/javaAPI/rest/secured/`message`

Comment: still 404 @HarryCoder

Comment: This link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022114/org-glassfish-jersey-servlet-servletcontainer-classnotfoundexception could help you I hope. But try delete class at the end <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer`.class`</servlet-class>

Comment: solved, thanks dude