# Jersey 2 with Maven Jetty Plugin - Class Not found Error

Tags: java, maven, jersey-2.0, maven-jetty-plugin

I try to run a web application with maven's jetty plugin. I have created a maven project. Here you see an excerpt of the pom:

```
...
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.19.v20190610</version>
        <configuration>
            <!-- <jettyXml>src/jetty.xml</jettyXml>-->
            <supportedPackagings>
                <supportedPackaging>jar</supportedPackaging>
            </supportedPackagings>
        </configuration>
       </plugin>
..
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
       <version>${jersey.version}</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
       <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>  
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
     </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
       </dependency> 
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
          <version>${jersey.version}</version>
       </dependency>
```

Further, I have a web.xml:

```
<web-app version="3.0">

    <display-name>WebApp</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param> 
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>main.java</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I try to `run mvn jetty:run` I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22023981/3579222) high voted post - I followed the recommendations but it is not working. Do you have any idea?

EDIT: I want to use the web.xml