# Dynamic Web Project Jersey Servlet: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jersey, web.xml

I'm making a sample Dynamic Web Project with jersey servlet however I am facing this class not found exception. Here is the **Stack Trace:**

```
Jan 19, 2023 3:33:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet [WebService] as unavailable
Jan 19, 2023 3:33:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [WebService] in web application [/web] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1437)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1245)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:537)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:908)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4906)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5198)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:926)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
```

I have searched different solutions that more or less give the following solutions:

1. Download Jersey Servlet Jar and add to WEB-INF/lib folder
2. Add Jars to build path
3. Add jars in Jersey servlet /ext folder to tomcat/lib folder.

I've tried all three of these solutions but It hasn't resolved my issue.

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="5.0">
  <display-name>web</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.dbiz.servlet.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.dbiz.webservice.TestWS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Jar files in Build Path**
[image]

I've tried all the solutions I could find online, any hint or suggestion will be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022114/org-glassfish-jersey-servlet-servletcontainer-classnotfoundexception)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer unfortunately no, I've gone through this post and made sre I've v2 in both my jar files and my web.xml

Comment: Which of those jars is the class in? They don't look like they're currently in WEB-INF/lib, so did you mark them as needing to be deployed with the Deployment Assembly property page for the project?

Comment: javax.servlet-5.1.12.jar looks suspicious. It has been released in 2006. You should have jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:4.0.4 from 2020 or javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1 from 2018.